# Using WebAudio API, how to add short crossfade when skimming to avoid audio "popping"

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, cross-fade

Im using wavesurfer.js to produce a visualisation of an audio source (player). I'd like to add a short crossfade whenever the user clicks the player to skim the audio.

I looked at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/
Searching for Web Audio crossfade only seem to produce results, which discuss about crossfading between 2 different audio sources, but I want a crossfade on a single source.

Is there a preferred way to do this? One way I guess would be for there to be an on click event on the player element, then fade out + fade in? Or maybe have 2 audio sources of which 1 is no sound?

Comment: I think, per definition, crossfading is the process of fading one sound/track out and another in, so I'm not sure what you mean by crossfading a single sound/source? If it's in fact the fade out followed by a fade in you're trying to achieve, then yes, do it on a click event and use the automation methods of a gain node that you connect your source node to.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a gain node, which ramps to 0 and back to 1 which would smooth the fade. This would add a small amount of latency however.

so when the user clicks on the player to skip:

-ramp the gain node to zero using `AudioParam.linearRampToValueAtTime()`

-skip to the part of the track

-ramp the gain node up to 1, also using linear ramp.

the fade would only have to be a few ms to remove the pops/clicks

link to web audio [AudioParam.linearRampToValueAtTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam/linearRampToValueAtTime)